# Custom button Error: sforce is not defined

Tags: apex, javascript

I have a custom object "Prospect__c" and would like to convert that to a Contact on button click. I get the

> A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was encountered: sforce is not defined

Any ideas why? Thanks.

Here's my calss:

```
global with sharing class ProspectConversion {
    webService
    static void convertProspectToContact (ID ProspectID) {
        List <Prospect__c> lstProspect = new List <Prospect__c>();
        //List of fields to push to Contact Object
        lstProspect =     [
                        SELECT
                        ID,
                        contact_name__c,
                        locale__c,
                        email__c,
                        phone__c,
                        type__c,
                        description__c,
                        Billing_Zip_Code__c,
                        Billing_Street__c,
                        Billing_Country__c,
                        Billing_City__c
                        FROM Prospect__c
                        WHERE ID =: ProspectID
                        ];

        List <Contact> lstContact = new List <Contact> ();

        for(Prospect__c pros : lstProspect) {

            lstContact.add(new Contact (

            LastName = pros.contact_name__c,
            Locale__c = pros.locale__c,
            Email = pros.email__c,
            Phone = pros.phone__c,
            Description = pros.description__c,
            Billing_Zip_Code__c = pros.Billing_Zip_Code__c,
            Billing_Street__c = pros.Billing_Street__c,
            Billing_Country__c = pros.Billing_Country__c,
            Billing_City__c = pros.Billing_City__c
            ));


        }

        INSERT lstContact;

    }
}
```

And my JavaScript button:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/32.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/32.0/apex.js")}
var Prospect__c = new sforce.SObject("Prospect__c"); 
   Prospect__c.ID = '{!Prospect__c.Id}';   
   Prospect__c.converted__c = 'True';
   dt= new Date();
   dt.setDate(dt.getDate()+0);
   Prospect__c.converted_date__c = dt;
var result = sforce.apex.execute("ProspectConverion","convertProspectToContact",{ProspectID : "{!Prospect__c.Id}"});
```

Comment: Rename `ProspectConverion` to `ProspectConversion` in the Javascript code :)

Comment: Yes, of course. These pesky little characters going missing :P
But sadly, I still get the error!

Comment: url is wrong.... Try `/soap/ajax/32.0/connection.js`

Comment: FYI, I've also changed the title of the post, feel free to revert it.

Comment: @sam_s You should add that as an answer .Looks perfect to me .

Comment: @MohithShrivastava that's fine. Same answer for this question already posted.

Comment: @sam_s Thanks for the comment. That solved it. Since you were the first to mention that, could you please add that as an answer so I can mark it solved?

Comment: Glad it helped. Please mark @Ratan answer as I would post the same one. Thanks.

Comment: I have one more question and I'm not sure if I post a new one.

Comment: I added try catch in the end of my class and added Success / Error in the button code, which works fine. But how can I redirect to the newly created Contact? Tried PageRedirect without any luck. I don't want to append the code in my original question. Should I open a new question? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct link.. This should solve your issue..

```
{!requireScript("/soap/ajax/36.0/connection.js")}

{!requireScript("/soap/ajax/36.0/apex.js")}

sforce.connection.sessionId = '{!$Api.Session_ID}'; // Add this line as well
```

**[Source](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_connecting.htm)**